# Check if randomly generated value already exists in hash

Tags: perl

If I have a Perl hash, and I randomly generated a numeric value, how can I get my code to check if the randomly generated value already exists in the hash?

Comment: (Google is your friend here. This is a perfect example of something you could easily have looked up for yourself.)

Comment: @Mort I was going to say that, but for someone new it's not that easy to find. Sure `values` and `exists` can be easy enough, but the `reverse` trick is not that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`exists` built-in](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html).

To check for keys:

```
my %foo = ( bar => 1 );
if (exists $foo{foo}) {
   print "key foo exists";
}
if (exists $foo{bar}) {
   print "key bar exists";
}
```

This code will print

```
key bar exists
```

To check for values, you need to [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) the hash first. Remember hashes are lists, so if they are reversed all the keys become values. You will may some data if a value exists more than once already, but if all you want to know is whether a value exists, that's not relevant.

```
my %foo = ( bar => 1, baz => 2, qrr => 1 );
my %reversed = reverse %foo;
if (exists $reversed{1}) {
   print "value 1 exists";
}
if (exists $reversed{3}) {
   print "value 3 exists";
}
```

This will print

```
value 1 exists
```

Comment: *"You* ***may*** *lose some data"*! And if `%reverse` is only used once then it's probably quicker to use `List::Util::any { $_ == 3 } values %foo`